# Rewrite rule for files that exist - especially index - can't redirect to index.php when http://xxxxx/index is typed in

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been at this for several hours now and its driving me crazy ... so here goes ... a vanilla Apache2 set up with /var/www as the document root. I've added the directory mvc in accordance with the excellent YouTube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw28-krO7ZM ... the problem occurs within 3 minutes of Part 1 ... adding the .htaccess with lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

No problem ... works fine for everything typed in like `http://localhost/mvc/fjfjjd` gets redirected to the controller .. the issue is when you type `http://localhost/mvc/index` it 404's straight away with the /var/log/apache2/error.log saying

```
[Fri Mar 07 19:09:25.337658 2014] [negotiation:error] [pid 17826] [client 127.0.0.1:47677] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/mspCostModel/index (None could be negotiated).
```

I have tried various Rewrites from the answers on this site like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php?url=$1 [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

or this ...

```
RewriteEngine On

# first line: If the filename contains public.php, dont rewrite again.
# second line: If the requested URI contains /public, rewrite to public.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/public.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public.php?$1 [L]

# Now here layed the problem, you do NOT want to rewrite the requested URI IF it is pointing to an actual file on the server.
# Thus, a condition for rewriting to index.php, is that the file does not exist.
# The second condition is that the directory does not exist. Not sure you need that though.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$ [L]
```

I have got somewhere in debugging in that if I add a file called test.php and I go to `http://localhost/mvc/test` I can replicate the 404 error whereas test.php fully qualified takes me to the controller ...

I've also tried just rewriting everything `RewriteRule .*$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` with the same 404

but to no avail ... is there a way of re-directing/re-writing `http://localhost/mvc/index` to go to the controller at index.php??? Would greatly appreciate any help with this ... I know its unlikely someone will type `http://www.example.com/index` but it could occur ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit is the important part of the error: `[negotiation:error]`

You need to turn mod_negotiation OFF by adding:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: fixed it immediately ... without equivocation ... genius ... many thanks ... ;-)